# C++ template function returns different value with and without use of constexpr

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c++11, templates

I have a template function `array_size` which takes a C-style array by reference and returns its size:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t array_size(T (&)[N]) noexcept {
  return N;
}
```

With this, the following works as expected:

```
int main() {
  int a1[]{1, 2, 3};      // a1's size is 3
  int a2[array_size(a1)]; // a2'2 size is also 3
}
```

If I remove the `constexpr` in the template function declaration however, the size of `a2` becomes `4295032832`. The number also does not change between multiple runs.

My question: What is going on if I omit the `constexpr` keyword?

I am using gcc 9.3.0 on ubuntu.

Comment: If you remove `constexpr` then `a2` is a VLA which is not allowed in standard c++.

Comment: Specifically, although GCC allows them, `sizeof` does not work correctly for VLAs.

Comment: `constexpr`, for the function, is strictly required when the returned value is used in a constant expression (like the size of a C-style array). If you compile adding `-ansi -pedantic`, you should get the warning "ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘a2’"

Comment: So there is no way to tell where this weird number is coming from?

Comment: Depends on how you get that number. Your code doesn't show that.

Comment: @cigien You're right, I did not specify that. When using sizeof(a2) / sizeof(a2[0]) I get 3 as expected, but my ide, clion shows 4295032832.

Comment: I think it's UB to use `sizeof` on a VLA.

Comment: @SebastianWilke - Are you sure that `4295032832` is the size of the array and not a memory address?

Comment: @max66 clion shows the type of a variable in braces. for example: `a1 = {int[3]}` and for a2 it shows: `a2 = {int[140734256530860]}` when debugging. It might be a combination of non ISO C++ compliant code and clion's way of handling it. I have not been able to figure out where this number is coming from.

Comment: @SebastianWilke - I suspect you've got the point and that clion manage both `a1` and `a2` as iso C++ arrays, so objects memorized in stack, but fail to correctly analyze `a2` because its size is a run-time value and it's memorized (I suppose) in the heap.